# Perl XS included from a "use lib" directory can't be found by ISAPI

Tags: iis, perl, isapi

I have a Perl web application that runs on both Apache and IIS6 on Windows Server 2003.  On Apache this script works just fine.  In IIS using ISAPI, I am getting the following error message:

> Software error:
>   Can't load
>   'lib/auto/Sub/Name/Name.dll' for
>   module Sub::Name: load_file:The
>   specified module could not be found at
>   C:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 230. 
>   at lib/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm line 10
>   Compilation failed in require at
>   lib/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm line 10.
>
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   lib/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm line 10.
>   Compilation failed in require at (eval
>   39) line 3.   ...propagated at
>   C:/Perl/lib/CGI/Carp.pm line 314.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   My/Schema.pm line 2. Compilation
>   failed in require at...

When NOT using ISAPI in IIS it runs fine.  We would prefer to continue using ISAPI in our IIS environments.  Why can't it find this module, even though it does when running normal Perl?

EDIT:

We were calling it with relative paths.

```
use lib qw{My lib};  # line in question
use My::Schema; # explodes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobrule, over on stack overflow, gave us an enlightening comment. The relative path was different between using the vanilla Perl interpreter and ISAPI.

```
use lib qw{My /Inetpub/wwwroot/cgi/lib};  # a little more specific...
use My::Schema;  # not nearly as much dying now.
```

Thanks for the help!